# Jackson deserialization of base64 byte[] - any simple way?

Tags: java, arrays, jackson, base64

Consider the following class:

```
class MyObject {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name = "Hello world";
    @JsonProperty("data")
    byte[] data = new byte[] {10, 20, 30, 40};
}
```

In the main class I have:

```
class Main {
    MyObject mo1 = new MyObject(), mo2 = new MyObject();
    List<MyObject> myList = Arrays.asList(mo1, mo2);
    byte[] serialize() {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(myList);
    }
    void deserialize(byte[] in) {
        myList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, List.class);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the value of `data` is saved as base64 (and it's correct) but when deserializing, `data` is not being converted back to `byte[]`, rather as `_StringWithBase64_.getBytes()`.

Is there any solution without using custom deserializer, like configuring `ObjectMapper` to decode base64 when loading into `byte[]`?

Comment: `myList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() { });`

Comment: @Andreas, where does that answer his specific question?
I do not believe this is a duplicate of that, though I may be missing something.
I don't see where that question addresses Jackson's handling of byte arrays.

Comment: @Andreas works as charm :)

Comment: Fascinating. That is really cool. How does that work?

Comment: @jhyry When you call `readValue(in, List.class)`, using a *raw* `List`, it doesn't know what type of object is in the list, i.e. what class to instantiate, so it simply creates a `Map`, i.e. you end up with a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Creating an anonymous subclass of `TypeReference` allow you to specify the type of object in the `List`.